# difference between uploadfile and uploadfilewithuniquename in WebRequestMethods.Ftp

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest, ftpwebresponse

Two questions here :

1)difference between WebRequestMethods.Ftp.uploadfile and WebRequestMethods.Ftp.uploadfilewithuniquename?

2)When i do an upload file using the code below for an already existing file would it override the file.And is it safe to assume that it would always override?

```
         public static void Main ()
    {
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");


        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
 // what if i use  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFilewithuniquename;



        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

        // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
        byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

        response.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These methods refer to the FTP commands [STOR and STOU](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/Internet/node127.html).

If the logged in user has the privs, then `STOR` (WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile) will create a new file or overwrite an existing file.